# AWS RDS PostgreSQL cross region replication streaming or back slot window

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, replication

I am trying to do the PoC for RDS PostgreSQL replication across multi-region

I went though these links [[replication](http://%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html), [streaming](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-amazon-rds-postgresql-replication/#:%7E:text=Intra%2DRegion%20replication,any%20reason%20delayed%2C%20replication%20lags) ] docs and found the streaming info, in order to create a read replication , AWS RDS PostgreSQL uses Postgres native streaming replication. Data changes at the source instance stream to Read Replica using streaming replication.

But I am not able to understand the configuration on what is the stream slot window to stream the WAL logs..

is it every second or as soon as each transnation is written to WAL or is it based on the count like after 'n' transaction WAL logs etc?